# ¿Cómo encapsular varias variables en un único objeto (POO)?

Tags: java

Hola tengo una clase que la estoy modificando para que sea mas eficiente. Y no consigo avanzar mas. Tengo distintos atributos para las casillas de un juego pero quiero encapsularlos todos en un objeto `Tipo_Casilla` que tenga el valor numérico y su representación gráfica.

Éste es el código actual:

```
//CONSTANTES

private static final int TIPO_VACIA = 1;
private static final int TIPO_LIMITE = 2;
private static final int TIPO_ITEM = 3;
private static final String TIPO_VACIA_TEXTO = " ";
private static final String TIPO_LIMITE_TEXTO = "\"";
private static final String TIPO_ITEM_TEXTO = "·";
//ATRIBUTO DE LA CLASE
private int tipo;

public Casilla(int getTipo) {

    int lmte = TIPO_LIMITE;
    int item = TIPO_ITEM;
    int nada = TIPO_VACIA;
    }

    public int[][] creaCasillasTableroJuego() {

    int lmte = TIPO_LIMITE;
    int item = TIPO_ITEM;
    int nada = TIPO_VACIA;

int[][] casillas = new int[][]{
    {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte},
    {lmte, item, item, item, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, item, item, item, item, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte},
    {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, nada, nada, nada, lmte, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, item, item, lmte},
    {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, item, item, item, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, item, item, item, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte, item, lmte, lmte, lmte, item, lmte},
    {lmte, item, item, item, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte, nada, nada, nada, nada, nada, lmte},
    {lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte, lmte}
    };

    return casillas;
}


    public boolean laCasillanoEsLimite(int[][] casillas, int x, int y)      {

    if (Posiciones.esUnaCoordenadaCorrecta(casillas, x, y)) {
        return casillas[x][y] != TIPO_LIMITE;
    }

    return false;
}

public boolean NohayItem(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {

    if (Posiciones.esUnaCoordenadaCorrecta(casillas, x, y)) {
        return casillas[x][y] == TIPO_ITEM;
    }

    return false;
}

public void vaciaCasilla(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {

    if (Posiciones.esUnaCoordenadaCorrecta(casillas, x, y)) {
        casillas[x][y] = TIPO_VACIA;
    }
}

public String casillaATexto(int[][] casillas, int x, int y) {

    if (Posiciones.esUnaCoordenadaCorrecta(casillas, x, y)) {
        switch (casillas[x][y]) {
            case TIPO_VACIA:
                return TIPO_VACIA_TEXTO;
            case TIPO_LIMITE:
                return TIPO_LIMITE_TEXTO;
            case TIPO_ITEM:
                return TIPO_ITEM_TEXTO;
            default:
                return "";
        }
    }

    return null;
    }

//METODOS GET Y SET
public int getTipo() {
    return tipo;
}

public int setTipo() {
    return tipo;
}
}
```

Comment: para inicializar las casillas por que no usas un doble `for` y te ahorras ese tochazo ?

Comment: No se entiende tu pregunta. ¿Lo que quieres es hacer una enumeración de tipos de casillas que tenga atributos de tipo numérico y texto para ser usada en otras partes del código?

Comment: Quiero pasar el codigo estructurado a POO. Solo he podido crear un constructor y un atributo. 
    -private int tipo;  +public Casilla(int getTipo)

Comment: Aparte de tipo, que atributos tiene que tener una `Casilla`? Trata de describir los componentes que ya sabes que vas a necesitar, como `TablaDeJuego`, `Casilla`, que tipo de representación gráfica tienes en mente?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La forma más cómoda de conseguir lo que quieres es con una enumeración de las casillas que formarán tu mapa. Las enumeraciones van más allá de una simple lista de valores y pueden tener un código completamente funcional en el que puedes incluso implementar si se puede situar el jugador encima de ellas o si activan algún otro método cuando se ocupan, etc...

Mira este código que es el caso más simple:

```
public enum Tipo_Casilla {
    VACIA (1, " "),
    LIMITE (2, "\""),
    ITEM (3, ".");

    final int valor;
    final String representacion;

    protected int getValor() {
        return valor;
    }

    protected String getRepresentacion() {
        return representacion;
    }

    Tipo_Casilla (int valor, String representacion){
        this.valor = valor;
        this.representacion = representacion;
    }
}
```

Con esto tienes tus tres tipos de casillas y puedes acceder a dos de sus principales atributos (valor `int` y representación gráfica `String`). Aquí te hace el listado:

```
System.out.println("Lista de tipos de casillas disponibles:");
    for(Tipo_Casilla tc : Tipo_Casilla.values()){
        System.out.println(String.format("Casilla tipo %s con valor %d y representación '%s'", tc, tc.getValor(), tc.getRepresentacion()));
    }
```

Que tiene la siguiente salida:

> Lista de tipos de casillas disponibles:
>   Casilla tipo VACIA con valor 1 y representación ' '
>   Casilla tipo LIMITE con valor 2 y representación '"'
>   Casilla tipo ITEM con valor 3 y representación '.'

En este caso tu arreglo de casillas pasaría a ser un arreglo `Tipo_Casilla[][]`, aunque te recomiendo que te crees una clase `Mapa` para gestionar las casillas y otros datos más (que además puede inicializar todas las casillas como vacías y el borde del mapa como límite y ya sólo centrarte en asignar los valores de ítems y otros límites)